# Deploy do not render React component in Astro

Tags: reactjs, deployment, components, react-props, astrojs

I am facing an issue with a React component in Astro. It works when I host locally, but in the deployed version, the component is not rendering. It seems to be a problem with the props that may be undefined, but I couldn't fix it.

This is my React Component:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';

export default function ImageSlider({ props }) {
    console.log(props);

    return (
        <Swiper
            spaceBetween={50}
            slidesPerView={1}
            onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
            onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        >
            <p>Test 2.</p>
            {props.map((image, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                    <img src={`/projects/Barrio_Walsh/${image}`} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
                </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper>
    );
}
```

And this is the Layout that sends the props to the component:

```
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation.astro';
import { ViewTransitions } from 'astro:transitions';
import '../styles/global.css';
import MySwiper from '../components/MySwiper';

interface Props {
    title: string;
}

const { title } = Astro.props;
const allPosts = await Astro.glob("../pages/projects/*.md");
const currentPath = Astro.url.pathname;
const currentProject = allPosts.find(post => post.url === currentPath);
const imagenes = currentProject?.frontmatter.imagenes;

// ... (other declarations)

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="generator" />
    <title>{title}</title>      
    <ViewTransitions />
</head>
<body>
    <Navigation/>
    <div style="padding: 20px">
        <h1 class="text-5xl font-extrabold dark:text-white" style="text-align: center; color: black; font-weight: bold;">{ ProjectTitle }</h1>
        <slot/>
        {project && imagenes && <MySwiper props={imagenes} client:load/>}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The array with images sent as a prop is from a .md file.

When I hardcode a correct image directory, it works, but when it's from the .md, it does not work on the deploy.

Comment: Which provider and integration (if any from astro.config.mjs) are you using?